# After the Spring boot source code is compiled, it starts to report an error in debug mode

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to analyze the source code of spring boot.

I compiled the source code of spring boot 2.2.9 RELEASE, and no errors were reported. And use this version as a dependency of my test project, and the test project can be started normally in IDEA.

But when I start the project in debug mode in IDEA it produces an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/collections/AbstractMutableMap
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:825)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:723)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.debug.internal.DebugProbesImpl.<clinit>(DebugProbesImpl.kt:30)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.debug.AgentPremain.<clinit>(AgentPremain.kt:26)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.collections.AbstractMutableMap
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 17 more
    *** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
    FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64553', transport: 'socket'
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've looked at many resources online, but no one seems to have encountered a similar error.

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the version of IntelliJ IDEA? Could be caused by https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-15750

Comment: The problem was solved after I upgraded the version of IDEA from 2021.1 to 2021.3. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 in the scope of https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-15750

Feel free to upgrade your installation